# headers not working on a livesite

Tags: php, mysql, header

My headers were working on my localhost but not working online.

```
<?php
require_once 'func/func.php';


if(isset($_POST['sub'])){

$user = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['username']));
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['pass']);
$sql = "select * from register where matric = '$user' and passw ='$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));


if($num == 1){


$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'];
$_SESSION['trader'] = $row['trader'];
$_SESSION['pic'] = $row['passport'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
       ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);


         flush();
       header("Location: home/home.php");
                    die('should have redirected by now');


   echo $pass;
     }else{
  echo "Invalid User Name or Password";

   }
}


  ?>
 <html><head>

 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="" method="post">
<table width="409" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
 <tr>
<td width="166">User Name</td>
<td width="215">

    <input type="text" name="username" id="text1">

</tr>
 <tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><p>

    <input type="password" name="pass" id="password1">

</tr>
  <tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="sub" type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
</tr>
   </table>
   <? if(isset($msg)) echo $msg; ?> </form>

 </body></html>
```

the func  file contains the session and mysqli connect file it is working on localhost.
with all errors on it is not dispaying error. it is outputing shoul have redirected by now. please help me out

Comment: Have you check error_log file ???

Comment: @bolaji try to use absolute url like http://yourdomain.com/home/home.php

Comment: tried it but not working

Comment: File does not exist: /home/unilorin/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://unilorinconnect.com/login.php

Comment: i can load the destination page and the session is set but tohe header is not working and the error in the log is above

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect works.
The problem is the URL is not correct.

Try it like this:

```
header("Location: http://site.com/home/home.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
header("Location: ./home/home.php");
```